# In gnuplot, how do I place the key some distance from the border?

Tags: gnuplot

How can I place the key some distance from a given border? For instance if I run `set key below` I can place the key below the graph, but it's too close and actually overlaps the xlabel. How can I place it some distance *further*, something like `set key below 1` to put it 1 below the default below position?

To clarify, I know I can place it manually with `set key at x,y`, but that involves manually looking for the right place. This requires manual calculation and adjustment to, for example, get it centered. I just want to put it a bit below its default `below` position.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a little extra height to the legend so that there is effectively more space between the bottom border of the plot and the legend content:

```
set key below height 2
set xlabel "this is the x axis label"
plot sin(x)
```

gives

[image]